# Can't install cocoapods, report on pod setup

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods, osx-mavericks

I was following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 to install `cocoapods` on my MacBook (Mavericks 10.9.5).

I have successfully used this commands

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

But then whenever i use `pod setup` i get this log

```
/Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/xcodeproj-0.19.3/lib/xcodeproj/plist_helper.rb:140:in `<module:CoreFoundation>': uninitialized constant Fiddle::NULL (NameError)
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/xcodeproj-0.19.3/lib/xcodeproj/plist_helper.rb:70:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/xcodeproj-0.19.3/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/xcodeproj-0.19.3/lib/xcodeproj.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/gems/cocoapods-0.34.2/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /Users/tommy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@msf/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

It appears also if i type `pod install`.

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The latest version of cocoapods gem (v0.34.2) requires a version of xcodeproj gem >= 0.19.2. But the latest version of xcodeproj gem (0.19.3) causes this issue.

Managed to fix this by **fixing the xcodeproj version to 0.19.2.**

```
gem uninstall xcodeproj
gem install xcodeproj -v 0.19.2
```

or specify `gem 'xcodeproj', '0.19.2'` in your gemfile, then run bundle.

Comment: It's also worth noting that xcodeproj 0.19.3 seems to be working fine on Ruby 2.0.0, but this issue was happening on Ruby 1.9.3-p448 (for me anyway). So you can also try upgrading / switching your Ruby version.